# Disabled TextBox Style

Tags: c#, textbox, windows-runtime, styles

I have created a TextBox above a Path-Element (the Path Element draws a rectangular thing, which acts as the design of the textbox). Now I want to disable this TextBox with

```
valCon.ValueTextBox.IsEnabled = false;
```

This works so far. However, since I don't want the TextBox to have any Style (no Color, no Borders, etc.), but only a visible Text in it, I'm getting a small problem:

When the TextBox is disabled, it automatically receives a style which I can't get rid of. The Background changes to white, the Opacity changes to around 0.3 and Borders appear.

I can't seem to solve this problem by adding

```
valcon.ValueTextBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
valcon.ValueTextBox.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
```

etc.

It just seems to ignore this. Does anyone know a solution?

Greetings
Narakuvera

Comment: Did you define a style on the `TextBox` in XAML? It's not the best idea to set these values in code-behind. Try to change your view in XAML.

Comment: you want a disabled textbox permanently or you want to disable it on some event?

Comment: @nakiya No, I didn't define the style of the TextBox in XAML, because the Control I'm using the TextBox on is very dynamic, which means I need to do alot of calculations and changes in code behind.

Comment: @nit I want it permanently.

Comment: @user3701907 then why do you need TextBox. You can use Label or TextBlock

Comment: @nit The thing is that I'm using the Control with the TextBox for another Control, in which the TextBox is disabled permanently. However, in the first Control it isn't disabled permanently. It's kind of complicated to explain and I can't really post the whole code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take control over the template to achieve the same

here is a basic template for you with no border and no background TextBox

```
    <TextBox Text="hello">
        <TextBox.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <ScrollViewer Margin="0"
                              x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </TextBox.Template>
    </TextBox>
```

you can choose to set `IsEnabled="False"` and it will still remain border less

**Code behind approach**

```
        ControlTemplate ct = new ControlTemplate(typeof(TextBox));
        FrameworkElementFactory sv = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ScrollViewer));
        sv.Name = "PART_ContentHost";
        ct.VisualTree = sv;
        textbox1.Template = ct;
```

**WinRT code behind approach**

```
        string template = "<ControlTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" TargetType=\"TextBox\"><ScrollViewer Name=\"PART_ContentHost\" /></ControlTemplate>";
        ControlTemplate сt = (ControlTemplate)XamlReader.Load(template);
        textbox1.Template = сt;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I want to achieve that in code behind only. XAML is not an option for me in that case. Is there a possibility to achieve in codebehind what you just did?

Comment: yes you can achieve the same using code behind, let me try to convert this to code behind.

Comment: @ pushpraj Doesn't work sadly. FrameworkElementFactory is nonexistent, so is ControlTemplate.VisualTree. Also, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ControlTemplate does not accept any argument. Maybe we're using different versions? Anyways, I understand the principle, so I might be able to recreate it in VS2013 for Win8.1. Thanks alot! :)

Comment: `System.Windows; & System.Windows.Controls;` are the namespace for these elements in WPF

Comment: System.Windows.Controls; doesn't seem to exist and I can't find any reference for it. :/

Comment: I hope you are using WPF, it is by default included in every WPF application. it contains most of the foundation control including TextBox. are you developing for WinRT?

Comment: Oh, yes I'm developing for WinRT. Sorry, I forgot to mention that.